# download an attachment from office365 rest api knowing only the attachmentItemID

Tags: office365, office365api

Drag and dropping a file from a browser logged into `office365/outlook` gives me a JSON string with the attachmentItemId but not the message ID.

```
attachmentV{"itemType":"attachment","attachmentFile":{"attachmentItemId":"AAMkADhmNz......","name":"feb invoices archive.pdf","size":64276,"fileType":5,"type":"ItemIdAttachment:#Exchange"}}
```

Yet the only endpoints I can see for fetching an attachment require the messageID.

e.g. `GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{message_id}/attachments/{attachment_id}`

Is there a way to download an attachment without knowing the message id?

Answer (score 0):

best i could find so far is to search messages for the file name

`.../messages/?$search="attachment:{Name}"&$expand=Attachments`

and then loop through the returned messages and their attachments looking for the specific id.

not ideal... but it's working.

n.b. you have to replace any "/" characters with "-" and any "+" with "_" in the attachmentid when comparing with the id returned in the search.